# How to install PHP5 on Openshift?

Tags: php, installation, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I am trying to install PHP5 using the instructions available [here](https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache).

However, when I perform: `nohup ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR}/misc/make.sh &`, I get a:
`nohup: failed to run command .../make.sh: Permission denied` message on top of `nohup: ignoring input and appending output to nohup.out`.

I have tried `sudo`, but I don't have access as `sudo` (of course).

Does anyone have clear, complete and operational instructions to install PHP5 on Openshift?

Comment: You will need to get sudo access to be able to install it, try and get sudo access so you are able to setup php5.

Comment: There is no way Openshift will give me sudo access loool

Comment: You should log an issue on the github repository and ask for help there.

Comment: Just did: https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you are using Windows, or you just lost the permission information.

Choose one solution:

1. Try fetching files by `git clone`.
2. I just updated this repo. Try it out! It's easier now! (Follow the new README instructions)

Comment: I have tried to follow your instructions, but it still fails. I have described what I have done in the issue opened in github.

Comment: Still Windows problem. Read [this](https://github.com/laobubu/openshift-php5.5-cgi-apache/issues/1#issuecomment-119634371)

Comment: It works now with the latest instructions in the issue I opened.